# Probability of winning the lottery in Turkey

Tags: probability

Lottery Administration prints 10 million tickets with 7-digit numbers in Turkey. Of these tickets, 8.800.000 are quarter-price, 700.000 half-price and 500.000 full-price tickets. ( 4 times quarter tickets 4X8.800.000=35.200.000, 2 times half - price tickets 2x700.000 =1.400.000 and 500.000  full-price tickets.Totaly 37.100.000 tickets are sold. The quarter-price tickets are sold for A/4, half-price ones for A/2  and the full-price tickets are sold for A (A=70 Turkish Liras) For example, If someone with a full-price ticket wins the lottery, he/she gets the whole of the biggest bonus. (70 million Liras) If someone with a half-price ticket wins, he/she gets half of it, (70  million liras is shared between 2 persons i.e. 35 million, while one with a quarter-price ticket gets 1/4, i.e 17,5 million liras, meaning it is shared among the four 1/4 price tickets with 4 persons that holding   the same number.)
Totaly, there are 342 different  small and big bonuses at each raffle.(1x70 millions,1x7 millions, 10x1 million, 30x100.000, 100x10.000, 200x5.000  Liras) But,when a ticket wins  more than one bonus, only, the biggest one is given to the ticket's owner. (bonusses who guess for last 2,3, 4,5 or 6 digits are neglected here.)
Additionaly, for last numbers  one among 0,1,2,3,4 and  one among  5,6,7,8,9  two lucky  numbers  gain ticket price refund. 
I think there are a lot of   advantages of buying a 1/4-price ticket over  full-price tickets, I mean instead of buying a full-price ticket at A liras, buying FIVE  1/4-price tickets for A liras, (Because  as I mentioned above, selecting the last number from 0 to 4 or 5 to 9 bought  1 ticket price is refund.) win probability increases 5 times according to full-price ticket. In addition, 5 quarter-price (1/4)tickets can win different bonuses, individualy. Whereas full-price tickets are deprived from this possibility.
Question:
What would be the advantage if 5 quarter tickets are bougth instead of one full-price tickets  and how can it be calculated.?
What is the mathematical expectations totaly in 342  bonuses at each raffle.?

Comment: Are the values of the bonuses adjusted for the price of the ticket, or are they fixed?  You talk of quarter price tickets sharing a number, but there are $10^7$ tickets sold and $10^7$ seven digit numbers.  It seems more likely to an outsider the numbers are unique but the payout is adjusted based on what the ticket price was.  Please make sure you have the rules right.

Comment: If a full price ticket costs $70$ and wins $70,000,000$ one time in $10,000,000$ the return is only $10\%$.  Lotteries are usually bad deals, but I have never seen one this bad.  How much are the small prizes worth?  You make it seem they are not significant, but I wonder.

Comment: Dear Mr. Millikan, First I am so sorry, that I couldn't answer you on time because I was sick. I made that a little clearer about Lottary Ruffle in Turkey. So I editted, please look at the main page. Abdullah Cenkciler. cenkciler@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the expected value of the grand prize is greater for five $1/4$ price tickets than for one full price ticket.  The expected value it $25\%$ greater.  One easy way to see it is to think you could buy the four matching tickets and get all the same prizes as the full price buyer, then have one more quarter price ticket in addition.

If we ignore the chance you will win two bonuses, we can compute the expected value of a full price ticket.  The prizes given total $92$ million, so the expected value is $9.2$ lira.  This is far less than the $70$ lira ticket price.  The improvement for buying $1/4$ price is not nearly enough to overcome this.  Don't play.